# Can I change pandas.DataFrame.plot() stacked barplot behaviour?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

In pandas I'm plotting the following .describe() table using the standard pd.DataFrame.plot method:

[image: Raw data]

EDIT: CSV raw data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uQltao5atGgFFIkyiicHclpd7sHcduwf/view?usp=sharing

and the output:

[image: The graph]

The code I've used for this is:

```
test = dict(df.groupby('symbol')['growth_%'].describe())
testdf = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(test)
testdf[['25%', '50%', '75%']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6));
```

The specific behaviour I want to edit is the 50th percentile value. Right now, if the value is below 0 it will tag itself below the 25th percentile value, or if above 0 it will tag itself below the 75th percentile value.

I would like for the 50th percentile to always be in the middle of the 2 values and preferably not acttually impacting the length of the bars - that is to say not making the 25th percentile value look lower or the 75th percentile value look higher through summation.

I appreciate this is all the nature of a stacked bar chart and what I'm asking is more like having the 50th percentile on a second y axis so it doesn't actually impact the other bars. Is there a conveient way to produce what I'm describing from the df.plot() method? or do I need to create a secondary y axis and plot the 50th percentile seperately?

Comment: Can you put up some of your data? Maybe like the first 10 ticker symbols.

Comment: csv snippet here for you https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nAAk5X-XxwFzNehfNBqhANQoSUQYpD7I/view?usp=sharing but theres an image of the full dataset in the question

Comment: There are some transformations you've done that aren't clear, like the `['growth_%']` column. It might be easier to subset a few of your rows and then `pd.to_csv()` from there.

Comment: I'm really not sure how having the original data would help, but here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uQltao5atGgFFIkyiicHclpd7sHcduwf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The intent is to get to a minimum REPRODUCIBLE example. So, giving specifics, I loaded up the snippet of rows, loaded everything up, went to plot, and straight off the line, there was an error. Now, we can work on the `growth_%` column which you already have done, or we could work on the problem you were asking about. The original data -- not useful. But a dataframe or .csv that lets us reproduce what you have is useful.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could change the order of the series to plot like this:

```
test = dict(df.groupby('symbol')['growth_%'].describe())
testdf = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(test)
testdf[['50%', '25%', '75%']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6));
```

Output:

[image]

Resorted legend:

```
test = dict(df.groupby('symbol')['growth_%'].describe())
testdf = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(test)
ax = testdf[['50%', '25%', '75%']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6));
lh = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lz = list(zip(*sorted(zip(*lh), key=lambda x: x[1])))
ax.legend(*lz)
```

Output:

[image]

Lastly, with overlapping and not stacking bars:

```
test = dict(df.groupby('symbol')['growth_%'].describe())
testdf = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(test)
#ax = testdf[['50%', '25%', '75%']].plot.bar(figsize=(10, 6));
l1 = plt.bar(testdf.index, testdf['25%'])
l2 = plt.bar(testdf.index, testdf['75%'])
l3 = plt.bar(testdf.index, testdf['50%'])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend([l1,l3,l2],['25%', '50%', '75%' ])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this answers my primary question and gets the data to show in the order I'd like it, but it doesn't attempt to solve my second query which is to make it so that the extents of the bars are as per the 25% / 75% values, rather than summative with the 50% value

Comment: @niche97 Is this what you are looking for?  Third options?